# как использовать полученное значение в качестве имя переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить значение радиокнопки (например цвет продукта) и по нему получить цену.

```
$(document).on('click',"input[type=radio]:checked", function(){
 var prodCost = $(this).val();
});

var green = 150;
var totalCost = prodCost * 10 ;
```

Comment: Где надо использовать?

Comment: Добрый день.  Использую в учебных целях чтобы получить значение радиокнопки (например цвет продукта) и по нему получить цену. Можно прописать в значении сразу цену, но хотелось попробовать по другому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После тщательного допроса ТС наконец-то стало понятно,что ему надо)))

```js
var prices = {
  "blue": "120",
  "green": "150",
  "red": "194"
};
$('input[name=color]').on('click', function() {
  var prodCost = $(this).val();
  totalCost = 0;
  $.each(prices, function(key, value) {
    if (prodCost == key) totalCost = value * 10;
  });
  $('.rez').html(totalCost);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" value="blue" name="color">blue</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="green" name="color">green</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="red" name="color">red</label>

<p class="rez">не выбрано...</p>
```

Comment: уже понял, что  предоставил недостаточно информации, спасибо!

Comment: Ну тогда отмечай как решение!

Answer (score 0):

```
var prodCost ="";

$(document).on('click',"input[type=radio]:checked", function(){

     prodCost = $(this).val();
     console.log(prodCost);

    
   });

    var green = 150;
    var totalCost = prodCost * 10 ;
```

Comment: спасибо. но prodCost все равно равен green  а не 150.